# How to implement server side pagination in angularjs using angular-ui bootstrap.?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

Please suggest different methods to implement server side pagination using angular js and angular-ui bootstrap. I would be paginating a table listing using ng-repeat according to current page selected in angualr-ui bootsrap pagination directive. Since we need to avoid frequent calls to server. We need to fetch 50 items from server at a time. We are showing 10 items per page.Since we need to paginate to larger datasets we need to keep the ng-repeat model to always contain 50 items for performance reasons.

Answer (score 9):

DirPaginate is something that'll meet the requirements of this question

Please see this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xmjmIId0c9Glh5QH97xz?p=preview) for demo of this.

When using server side pagination, you'll have to get JSON response in this format.

**Format of your JSON response**

```
{
    Count: 1400,
    Items: [
        { // item 1... },
        { // item 2... },
        { // item 3... },
        ...
        { // item 25... }
    ]
}
```

The only thing that you need to watch is that you get total count of items in your database because you'll need this to pass it to our directive.

**Format of your angular Controller**

```
.controller('UsersController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.users = [];
    $scope.totalUsers = 0;
    $scope.usersPerPage = 25; // this should match however many results your API puts on one page
    getResultsPage(1);

    $scope.pagination = {
        current: 1
    };

    $scope.pageChanged = function(newPage) {
        getResultsPage(newPage);
    };

    function getResultsPage(pageNumber) {
        // this is just an example, in reality this stuff should be in a service
        $http.get('path/to/api/users?page=' + pageNumber)
            .then(function(result) {
                $scope.users = result.data.Items;
                $scope.totalUsers = result.data.Count
            });
    }
})
```

and finally this is an example of how you'll integrate it in your html

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="UsersController">
    <table>
        <tr dir-paginate="user in users | itemsPerPage: usersPerPage" total-items="totalUsers" current-page="pagination.current">
            <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <dir-pagination-controls on-page-change="pageChanged(newPageNumber)"></dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
```

Please see Working with Asynchronous data section of this page.

https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination#working-with-asynchronous-data

Answer (score 1):

I used the dir-pagination library. It's very easy to use and also light weight. The [documentation](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) is very good as well.

Here is an [implementation](https://ciphertrick.com/2015/08/31/server-side-pagination-in-angularjs/) example.

Edit: Oops just noticed, Raman Sahasi has given the same suggestion in his answer. Will keep mine, I believe the end-to-end implementation tutorial would be useful for some.