# Angular JS large table performance issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been finding the solution for large data tables in angular js with bi-direction binding. Unfortunately I could not get best solution.

As shown below, I'm trying to load the data more than 5000 rows with 20 columns in single table. But application performance is very poor loading and taking time 3 to 4 minutes. After investigation using Angular watchers add on. I found 275,000 watchers in single page due to large data in single table.

Is there any way to improve the performance and reducing the watchers?

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col ng-style="{ width: h.columnWidth}" data-ng-repeat="h in vm.copyHeadersDeepCopy track by $index"></col>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="l in vm.copyColumns">
        <td ng-class="(l.rowSelected == true)?'selected':''"
            ng-repeat="c in l.values"
            title="{{c.parameterValue}}">
            <div title="{{'No Value Defined' | translate}}"
                 data-ng-if="vm.getCopyCellInformations(c).type == 'hole'">
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>
            </div>
            <div title="{{'empty' | translate}}"
                 data-ng-if="vm.getCopyCellInformations(c).type == 'grouped'">

            </div>
            <div title="{{c.parameterValue}}"
                 data-ng-if="vm.getCopyCellInformations(c).type == 'value'">
                <i class="fa" style="cursor: pointer"
                   data-ng-show="c.parameterValue"
                   data-ng-click="vm.toggleNode(c)"
                   data-ng-class="c.active ? 'fa-check-square-o' : 'fa-square-o'"></i>
                {{c.parameterValue}}
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You may use <ng2-smart-table> for that

Comment: If you don't want to use third-party libraries, think about finding an approach that renders **just the visible part**. Repeaters should be clever enough to render in the DOM only the visible portion of the table, otherwise think about a **pagination** system, so that only X row will be rendered at once. Another approach is to use the "infinite scroll" approach, where rows are loaded on demand when the user scrolls the table. Either alternatives are usually implemented in many diffused plugins / angular components in general. This is an example: http://ui-grid.info/ or https://www.ag-grid.com/

Comment: get limited data from server side and set pagination on your front-end.

Comment: You should try angularjs datatable

Comment: https://ciphertrick.com/2015/08/31/server-side-pagination-in-angularjs/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38494411/how-to-implement-server-side-pagination-in-angularjs-using-angular-ui-bootstrap

Comment: use track by in all of the ng-repeat. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Tried with track by but no luck still same issue.

Comment: If you have some `$scope` that you know won't be updated you can add `::` before. It will be a one time bind and won't be watched. Example : `title="{{ ::c.parameterValue }}"`. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding